# $0^0 = 1$ or indeterminate?

Tags: calculus

Is $0^0 = 1$ or indeterminate?  I've heard a number of conflicting answers.
If it was indeterminate, how would

$$e^x = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

make sense since $e^0 = 1$?

Comment: It is one and indeterminate. Indeterminate doesn't mean undefined, rather it means not continuously defined.

Answer (score 1):

The sum you've written is short hand for

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{6}x^3+\ldots$$

You'll notice that I wrote $1$ and not $x^0$, so there is no problem with the equation $e^0=1$.

You are right, however, to say that $0^0$ is indeterminate.  In fact, for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, notice the following:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}a(x^2)^{(x^2)}=a$$

Comment: This implicitly assumes that $x^0=1$, and in particular $0^0=1$. Somewhat circular for my taste...

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what the context is. There are very good reasons to define $0^0 = 1$ like the one you just mentioned. Refer to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_power_of_zero) for a list of arguments for and against.